# Loop c:set variable using JSTL

Tags: jsp, jstl

How to loop and access 'somethings' variable from request scope in JSP page?

```
<c:set var="somethings" value="${fn:split('a,b,c', ',')}" scope="request"/>
<c:forEach items="somethings" var="some">
     ${some} // <= Expected show a b c, but why display 'somethings'?
</c:forEach>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You see "something" because items can be an object. In your case it's a string because it's not evaluated as an object. Try:

```
<c:forEach items="${somethings}" var="some">
     ${some} 
</c:forEach>
```

Note the $ and brackets.